# how can i change section height on all in one page

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<body class="signle-layout">

    <section id="home" class="pt-page pt-page-1" data-id="home">
<p>some html css js items</p>
      </section>
        <section id="about" class="pt-page pt-page-2" data-id="about">
<p>some html css js items</p>
          </section>
            <section id="services" class="pt-page pt-page-3" data-id="services">
<p>some html css js items</p>
              </section>
                <section id="clients" class="pt-page pt-page-4" data-id="clients">
<p>some html css js items</p>
                  </section>
                    <section id="contact" class="pt-page pt-page-5" data-id="contact">
<p>some html css js items</p>
                      </section>

</body>
<style>
.pt-page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: auto;
    left: 0;    
    display: flex;
     min-height:620vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.signle-layout{
    background: #f3f3f3;
    min-height: fit-content !important;
}


</style>
```

---

> I have single page website. Some of these pages are different sizes.
> And it is always based on the class with the highest height, even if I
> fix it, it still does not improve. By the way, I show each section as
> if it is a different page with transition.
> **When I open an additional class in each page and make the min-height with !importan part fit-content or write the size accordingly, I still
> see the background body part. You can see the example in the picture.
> always sets the section size based on the largest part.
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tiTs.jpg

Comment: If there is someone who can explain in detail, I can give more details. I have been working for days, but the mind is superior to the mind.

Comment: Start by closing the sections, then update the snippet I made you with relevant CSS

Comment: is there anybody ??

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined properties for section,
Please refer to these properties in your code.
But you have to specify the height for the largest section block.

```css
body{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
flex-direction:column;
}

section{
height:300px;
background:#AAAAAA;
color:Black;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
width:300px;
}
section p{
font-size:2rem;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<body>
<section>
<p>Section 1</p>
</section>
<br>
<section>
<p>Section 2</p>
</section>
<br>
<section>
<p>Section 3</p>
</section>
<br>
<section>
<p>Section 4</p>
</section>
<br>
</body>
```